# Seized in and sheered off with limited options

Tags: removal, bolts

Group,
  To put my situation into perspective:
I'm working on an electric motor. This motor contains a few semisensitive (temperature wise) sensors near the  power box. I have an approximately 4-5 inch long, approximately 3/8s bolt that is seized in pretty well. It's sat in pb blaster for probably a week or two prior to attempted extraction and with just a little oomph sent the head snapping off. Welding a nut onto it is not an option, same with cutting it, due to the fact the shaft is about 1/8th an inch inside of the threaded hole.  Due to the nature of the environment (gasses, oils, etc) as well as the tolerance of the sensor and components torching it is limited to almost entirely out. Moving it out of its location, because it's a pump motor, is also out of the question. The bolt in question is an original one, not quite so rusty (visibly) and feels like rather soft. Or at least, the exposed part was.

I've heard and had the horror stories with ez puts and with left handed drill bits so I'm quite apprehensive (read: terrified) to try to go through that(a second time). I have begin the slow and tedious process of drilling the hole out and was putting a thought together:

Do you think I would have any luck drilling it out, putting threads in the inside of it, and then using a slightly smaller bolt with jb weld on the threads and then trying to impact drill it off once cured and re-doused with pb?